# Add Account To Account Manager After Firebase Auth UI

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui, accountmanager

I am trying to take WhatsApp's approach to contact lists, where I simply sync my app's contacts with the devices contacts. I am using Firebase as my Authentication Platform and Database (Firestore). I am using Firebase Auth UI for Phone Number Authentication.

What I would like to achieve is my In-App contacts list basically load with my device contacts ONLY if those contacts have my app installed as well. Just like WhatsApp does.

I have already read the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/custom_auth) for `AccountManager` and seen a few tutorials [like this one](http://blog.udinic.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/) but cannot figure out how to put it all together.

**Questions I have are:**

1. What exactly is the role of the `AccountAuthenticator` and for what purpose would a developer use it? Do I need an `AccountAuthenticator` for my use case? Do I just need to do `AccountManager.addAccountExplicitly()` and that's it?
2. If I do need the whole API, how do I set it up with my Firebase Auth UI? The Auth UI is already handling the login flow and everything and I'm already storing a user object in Firestore.
3. In `AccountManager.addAccountExplicitly(accountName, accountType)`, what is Account Name supposed to be and Account Type supposed to be? Give an example.

**Here Is My Current Code For Firebase Authentication:**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_launch)
    tilName.visibility = View.GONE
    btnSignIn.visibility = View.GONE
    Handler().postDelayed({
        if (auth.currentUser == null) startActivityForResult(
            AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder()
                .setAvailableProviders(listOf(AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build()))
                .setTheme(R.style.LauncherTheme).build(), rcSignIn
        )
        else startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
    }, 1000)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == rcSignIn) {
        val response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data)
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val user = auth.currentUser!!
            tilName.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            btnSignIn.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            btnSignIn.setOnClickListener {
                if (etName.text!!.isNotEmpty()) user.updateProfile(
                    UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder().setDisplayName(etName.text.toString()).build()
                ).addOnSuccessListener { addUser(user) }.addOnFailureListener {
                    Log.e("Update User Profile", "Failed To Update User Profile", it)
                } else snackBar("You haven't provided a valid name in the Text Field")
            }
        } else Log.i("User Sign In", "Sign-In Process Failed", response?.error!!)
    }
}

private fun addUser(user: FirebaseUser) {
    pbSigningUp.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId.addOnSuccessListener {
        Log.i("Get FCM Token", "Device Token Retrieved Successfully: ${it.token}")
        db.collection("users").document(user.uid).set(User(user.displayName!!, user.phoneNumber!!, it.token))
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                Log.i("Add User", "New User Added Successfully: ${user.uid}")
                startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
            }.addOnFailureListener { e -> Log.e("Add User Failed", "Failed To Add New User", e) }
    }.addOnFailureListener { Log.e("Device FCM Token", "Failed To Retrieve Device Token", it) }
}
```

After my app returns from Firebase Auth UI, I ask him for his name and store everything in a user object on Firestore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the Account Authenticator is meant to be the interface between your application and your server, every time the user logs in. It serves the purpose of getting new Auth-Tokens and managing User Credentials with your server.

Since, Firebase already does all that for me, it would seem that the Account Authenticator is not required. **But it is**. It is highly recommended to create a **Stub Authenticator** and a corresponding Authenticator Service (even if you're not going to use it). The code for which can be found [here in the official Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-authenticator).

There isn't much after that. `AccountManager.addAccountExplicitly()` works just fine. To be safe I even extended the Activity to `AccountAuthenticatorActivity` and found no change in the way it functions - so it's completely fine to do so.

As far as the question of `accountName` and `accountType` goes.

- Account Name can be anything. Name, phone number, email... Whatever you want to identify your account by.
- Account Type should generally be your app's package name.

Hope this helps.